# Informatica scenario regarding unique sequence

Tags: informatica-powercenter

For the given input, how can I get the desired output?

Input

```
App id | App name 
123    | abc 
456    | cde 
123    | abc
```

Output

```
App id | App name 
123    | abc-1
456    | cde-1
123    | abc-2
```

I run my job the first time, the output should come as above. If I run the job a second time, the output should be:

```
App id | App name
123    | abc-3
456    | cde-2
123    | abc-4
```

Answer (score 0):

One way or another - you will need a dictionary. You can create a `Stored Procedure` that will take the 1st part of the name as input, check the last value in a dictionary table, increase it by 1 and return. Call the SP in the mapping